# jquery select for incrementing id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a number of elements that renders based on data on my dates. and generates increment div ids by

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#MainD1').on('click', function () {
                    $('#ShowD1').toggle();
                });
            $('#MainD2').on('click', function () {
                $('#ShowD2').toggle();
            });
            $('#MainD3').on('click', function () {
                $('#ShowD3').toggle();
            });
            $('#MainD4').on('click', function () {
                $('#ShowD4').toggle();
            });
            ....
            $('#MainDn').on('click', function () {
                $('#ShowDn').toggle();
            });
        });
```

I would like to replace this with something like "each" function which generates for each id, I used for loop but codes did not work inside of the loop.

My PHP codes:

```
@foreach ( $reled as $rele )
                <div style="display: none;">{{$ix++}}</div>
                <div id="MainD{{$ix}}">
                    <div class="released-item" id="myDIV">
                        <div><b>{{ $rele->customer_name }}</b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none;" id="ShowD{{$ix}}">
                    <div class="field-item">
                        <div>{{ $rele->customer_name }}</div>
                        <span class="text-muted text-xs">Full Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-item">
                        <div>{{ $rele->amount_word }}</div>
                        <span class="text-muted text-xs">Amount in Words</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-item">
                        <div>{{ $rele->amount_numb }}</div>
                        <span class="text-muted text-xs">Amount in Numbers</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-item">
                        <div>{{ $rele->customer_address }}</div>
                        <span class="text-muted text-xs">Customer Address</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-item">
                        <div>{{ $rele->date_accident }}</div>
                        <span class="text-muted text-xs">Date of Accident</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them all a class, and use DOM navigation to find related elements.

PHP:

```
@foreach ( $reled as $rele )
    <div style="display: none;">{{$ix++}}</div>
    <div id="MainD{{$ix}}" class="MainD">
        <div class="released-item" id="myDIV">
            <div><b>{{ $rele->customer_name }}</b></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="ShowD{{$ix}}" class="ShowD">
        <div class="field-item">
            <div>{{ $rele->customer_name }}</div>
            <span class="text-muted text-xs">Full Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
            <div>{{ $rele->amount_word }}</div>
            <span class="text-muted text-xs">Amount in Words</span>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
            <div>{{ $rele->amount_numb }}</div>
            <span class="text-muted text-xs">Amount in Numbers</span>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
            <div>{{ $rele->customer_address }}</div>
            <span class="text-muted text-xs">Customer Address</span>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item">
            <div>{{ $rele->date_accident }}</div>
            <span class="text-muted text-xs">Date of Accident</span>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".MainD").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".ShowD").toggle();
  });
});
```